# Are there any Audio/Sound NPAPI plugins available?

Tags: javascript, npapi, browser-plugin, audio

I've been searching for it for a very long time and can't seem to find any relevant items (I know about the VLC plugin and I don't think it supports sound effects for video games). I need something similar like [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org) or [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) (or an NPAPI wrapper for these two) or a DirectSound NPAPI plugin, or just anything as long as it can support loading .wav, .ogg, .mp3, .m4a, etc. and can play those sounds in multiple instances.

EDIT: The reason I'm trying the NPAPI route is because the Web Audio API isn't really ready for primetime yet. I already tried Chrome's implementation and it has a bit of latency when playing the sounds (and multiple instances of sounds). It's even hard (or maybe impossible) to pause-play sounds with the current API spec. I also tried Flash (via SoundManager 2) and it also suffers from latency. It's fine for games but not good for making music applications such as a drum sampler. I hope this clarifies. (Sorry for my English, it's not my first language)

Comment: any you want an npapi plugin instead of using existing html5, flash, etc because...?

Comment: I already tried the Web Audio API and Flash (via SoundManager 2) and there is some latency when playing the sounds. I also made a hack out of the plain audio element, cycling them per iteration but then it only works well for firefox 4 (higher versions of firefox and google chrome crash when multiple audio elements are created).

Comment: Here's a demo (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6p8FTP_wHBw) of the Firefox 'audio element hack' sound library that I made. It's being used by the 'Kontroller Press Play' drum sampler app that I made. It's running on Firefox 4 (portable)

Comment: There are quite a few Flash games out there, so i imagine proper and relatively low-latency sound should be possible with it.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche browser to flash plugin communication is not really that fast. Try SoundManager 2 to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing plugins that will do what you want, but if you have some good c++ experience you could build a plugin to do that with [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org).  The sound playback functionality you'd have to implement yourself, though.

Keep in mind that Chrome has [announced plans](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) to stop supporting plugins by the end of 2014 and Firefox will be blocking them by default starting in firefox 26, requiring users to specifically enable any plugins used on a page before they will work.  You also have the "fun" install issue.

In short, if you can do something without a plugin you should absolutely not be using a plugin.

Comment: I'm aware of FireBreath, but I don't have any c++ know-how to create a plugin. I also know about Chrome ditching NPAPI support (which, I think, is a bad move), and Firefox's 'click-to-enable' approach seems tolerable. I wouldn't normally settle for a plugin route (see my 'audio-element-hack' which I did for Firefox 4) unless the current set of technologies required for my apps/games aren't 'reliable' yet, as is the case for the current Web Audio API spec implementation.

Comment: I don't know of any existing options, unless quicktime might work for you.